# How does filebeat handle reliability when it outputs to Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, filebeat, reliability

It is known that Kafka can provide exactly-once delivery semantic after 0.11.0.0. And I expect to make filebeat output to Kafka that way. According to [KIP 98](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-98+-+Exactly+Once+Delivery+and+Transactional+Messaging#KIP-98-ExactlyOnceDeliveryandTransactionalMessaging-KeyConcepts), it requires some configs to be set properly, including `enable.idempotence`, `transaction.timeout.ms` and `transactional.id` for producer (i.e., filebeat) . But I cannot find these configs even in [the latest version of filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.x/kafka-output.html). So, I want to know if it is supported and how to achieve that if it is a yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, from the documentation of Filebeat and resources surrounding it, it is not possible to have exactly-once delivery with Filebeat. It currently utilizes the at-least once delivery, meaning you'll get the message 1 or more times.

Although Kafka can support exactly-once semantics, it appears that Filebeat does not support exactly-once semantics. Filebeat would need to implement those configurations to support exactly-once delivery.